# Как получить path с svg файла?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, svg, vector

Подскажите, как можно получить **path** с **svg** файла?

Например, есть такой файл:

```
<svg height="205px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 205 205" width="205px"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d=" M 0.00 0.00 L 49.47 0.00 C 35.55 0.87 22.07 7.38 12.95 17.97 C 5.37 26.51 0.95 37.59 0.00 48.93 L 0.00 0.00 Z"
    fill="#ffffff" />
<path d=" M 49.47 0.00 L 56.06 0.00 C 68.59 1.01 80.77 6.39 89.62 15.37 C 98.72 24.36 104.19 36.76 105.00 49.50 L 105.00 56.06 C 103.97 68.84 98.39 81.25 89.11 90.14 C 80.17 98.92 68.02 104.19 55.54 105.00 L 48.95 105.00 C 36.40 103.99 24.22 98.60 15.36 89.61 C 6.27 80.63 0.81 68.24 0.00 55.51 L 0.00 48.93 C 0.95 37.59 5.37 26.51 12.95 17.97 C 22.07 7.38 35.55 0.87 49.47 0.00 Z"
    fill="#243c82" />
<path d=" M 56.06 0.00 L 105.00 0.00 L 105.00 49.50 C 104.19 36.76 98.72 24.36 89.62 15.37 C 80.77 6.39 68.59 1.01 56.06 0.00 Z"
    fill="#ffffff" /></svg>
```

Нужно каждый **path** отдельно.

Comment: а в чем проблема, получать как-то программно? или вы не знаете как копировать и вставлять в др файл?

Comment: хм.... Конечно же программно! 
Имею код:
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.svg_image);

Sharp.loadResource(getResources(), R.raw.wheel)
                .into(imageView);

Comment: Использую эту [либу](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp) . . . Но в ней нету такой возможности. Может кто то знает какие то библиотеки, в которых есть такой метод.

Comment: Не знаю, мне что первое в голову приходит это объявить XmlPullParser подгрузить xml ку пробежаться по тегам path, и вытащить в массив String все path. Возможно есть способ проще, но я не знаю.

Comment: Тут можно, вроде, ограничиться подстрокой от `<path d="` до следующего `"`. Удаляя после нахождения найденное.